# .htaccess language subdomains affect other rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I know that there were many questions like this but I still can't solve the problem.

I am using following .htaccess code to change the language:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(en|us)\.domain\.com$
# Create an environment variable to remember the language:
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:%1]
# Now check if the LANGUAGE is empty (= doesn't exist)
RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} ^$
# If so, create the default language (=en):
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:en]
# WHATEVER THE LANGUAGE ADD IT TO THE URI:
RewriteRule (.*) $1?language=%{ENV:LANGUAGE} [QSA]
```

This adds `?language=variable` at the end of the address.

But for some reason the rest of the rules like this generate Internal Server Error:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)(|/)$ code.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Simple rules (without adding variables) similar to this one work fine:

```
RewriteRule ^stats(|/)$ stats.php [L]
```

I hope that someone will be able to tell me where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a `QSA` or your language param gets lost:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)(|/)$ code.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

There's nothing wrong with that rule, the 500 error may be caused by `code.php`

---

It looks like the language rules you have is what is looping, aside from adding a `QSA` to your other rules that add to the query string, you need to exclude appending "language=" when you already have it. So above the last language rule, add this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !language
```

So that that it looks like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !language
# WHATEVER THE LANGUAGE ADD IT TO THE URI:
RewriteRule (.*) $1?language=%{ENV:LANGUAGE} [QSA]
```

Comment: The problem disappears when I delete the presented code responsible for changing the language. I am sure that code.php is fine. It happens for all the rules passing additional variables extracted from the link. I could use cookies for changing the language but this would be a stupid workaround without actually solving the problem.

Comment: Awesome, it is working. I always have problems with mod_rewrite rules. It is the most difficult part of creating the website for me :D